# how to process all but one column before concatenating chunks when use chunks to read large csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, chunks

I have a large csv file (7GB) and I used these codes to read it in Pandas:

```
chunks=pd.read_table('input_filename', chunksize=500000)
df=pd.DataFrame()
df=pd.concat((chunk==1) for chunk in chunks)
```

This works for me because the file is one-hot encoded, so the `chunk==1` part convert 0s and 1s into boolean values, which saved me some memory usage.

Now I want to use this same method to read in another file, the only problem is that the new file has an `ID` column, which is not one-hot encoded. My question is: how can I keep the `ID` column intact and convert the rest columns in the same way?

I tried some subsetting techniques, including:

`df=pd.concat((chunk.loc[:, -1]==1) for chunk in chunks)`

but none of them worked so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
chunks = pd.read_csv('input_filename', chunksize=500000, index_col='ID')
df = pd.concat([chunk.astype(bool) for chunk in chunks]).reset_index()
```

Comment: I got the idea! But it throws out an error: `Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument`. And then I tried: `df=pd.concat((chunk.set_index('ID').astype(bool)) for chunk in chunks, ignore_index=True)`, still same error... Maybe I added the parenthesis in the wrong place?

Comment: Hi @MaxU, I tried that myself too. Still same error. Could it be due to different versions of Python/Pandas? My Python is 2.7.13, and my pandas is 0.20.2. Thank you!

Comment: After some trial and error, I found that after the `ignore_index=True` part is deleted, the code works. So here's what is working for me now `df=pd.concat((chunk.set_index('ID').astype(bool)) for chunk in chunks)'.